# getting a typeerror when trying to sum arguments using a function

Tags: python, argparse

So i am working on a budget calculator and i run into an error where i cant add the the expenses

Heres the error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jason/Documents/budgetcalc/./budgetcalc.py", line 50, in <module>
    totexpenses = exp.expenses(args.expenses)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

code used for the calculation:

```py
class Expenses(Budgeter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def expenses(self, expense_list):
        self.expenses = expense_list
        total = sum(self.expenses)
        return total

# instance 
exp = Expenses()
```

defined argument:

```py
parser.add_argument('--expenses', help='n amounts of expenses', nargs='*', type=int)
```

and heres the code for that argument:

```py
if args.expenses:
    totexpenses = exp.expenses(args.expenses)
    # print(f'${income} net income')
    print(f'${totexpenses} in expenses')
```

heres the full code if needed:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import sys

class Budgeter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wage = 0
        self.netincome = 0
        self.expenses = 0
        self.hours = 0

class Income(Budgeter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def income(self, wage, hours):
        self.wage = wage
        self.hours = hours
        self.netincome = (float(self.wage) * int(self.hours)) * 4.34
        return self.netincome

class Expenses(Budgeter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def expenses(self, expense_list):
        self.expenses = expense_list
        total = sum(self.expenses)
        return total
        
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--wage', help='enter a wage ($$/hr)')
parser.add_argument('--hours', help='hours per week')
parser.add_argument('--expenses', help='n amounts of expenses', nargs='*', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--interactive', help='get a prompt for easy use', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

pc_budgeter = Budgeter()
rawinc = Income()
exp = Expenses()

if args.wage and args.hours:
    if int(args.hours) <= 24:
        income = rawinc.income(args.wage, args.hours)

        if args.expenses:
            totexpenses = exp.expenses(args.expenses)
            print(f'${income} net income')
            print(f'${totexpenses} expenses')

        else:
            print('missing --expenses')
    else:
        print(f'there are only 24 hours in a day not {args.hours}')
else:
    parser.print_help()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The `Budgeter` class defines an integer attribute named `expenses`:

```
class Budgeter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wage = 0
        self.netincome = 0
        self.expenses = 0
```

... and then the `Expenses` class, inheriting from `Budgeter`, defines a method *also* named `expenses`:

```
class Expenses(Budgeter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def expenses(self, expense_list):
```

Rename one of those things to a different name.

By the way, you don't need `__init__` in the child class, because the only thing it does is call the parent `__init__`, which is the default behavior anyway.

Comment: ok that worked, i didnt know that the name mattered at all